# Rewrite condition (exclude folder) not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to exclude one folder from being rewritten when used underscore in the rule

```
#replace underscores with dashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/featured_item/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [OR]
RewriteRule (.+?)_(.*) $1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

but somehow `/featured_item/` is rewritten as `/featured-item/` anwyay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[OR]` condition is a problem here as for any request one of the condition will evaluate to true.

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/featured_item/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+?)_(.*) $1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.